# Help setting up separate MySQL server for rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

Maybe I am over complicating this in my head but I just don't know what to do next...

I have a slice configured with MySQL, Rails & Passenger. I am setting up a new slice to separate the front-end from the database.  The current server will become the database server and the new front-end will connect to it.  I am using Ubuntu 8.10 on both.

Can someone point me to a resource that will help me configure this properly?  I have never had to separate things out like this before but we are now thinking about scalability and this seems like an obvious first step.

What are the best resources for helping me through setting up separate database and front-end hosts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert but I think this really boils down to configuring mysql to [allow access](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html) from hosts other than localhost.

Secondly, you will have to change your database.yml to use tcp/ip to connect to mysql rather than a unix socket. Delete the 'socket:' line (or comment it out), and replace it with

```
host: <ip of mysql server>
```